# Decision Tree in android application based on openCV library

Tags: opencv, android-studio, decision-tree, android

I want to develop a real-time application based on decision tree. 
I use android and openCV. OpenCV provides CvDTree class, but I didn't know how to use it and I didn't found any example. Can you help me?

Thank you,